# RecyclerView espresso test click() not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ui-testing, android-espresso

I faced with strange espresso instrumentation test behavior. Clicking on recycler view's item not working.

**Click not happened here**:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

**But this workaround works**:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, recyclerClick()));

// ...

public static ViewAction recyclerClick() {
    return new ViewAction() {

        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return any(View.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "performing click() on recycler view item";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            view.performClick();
        }
    };
}
```

Is this Espresso or RecyclerView issue?

Comment: neither; espresso simply didn't "know" how to click on a recycler view. Once you provided it with a howto implementation, it knew, and it worked.

It would've been an issue if the second approach didn't work ;)

Comment: Have you tried to use onData instead of onView?

Comment: As we can see in official documentation for [Espresso.onData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#onData%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%3C?%20extends%20java.lang.Object%3E%29)

`Use this method to load (into the view hierarchy) items from AdapterView widgets (e.g. ListView).`

`RecyclerView` extends `ViewGroup`. So `onData()` can't be used with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be nothing to do with `RecyclerView` specifically. What Espresso does with its `ViewActions.click()` implementation is sending the `MotionEvent` to the center of the target view. Make sure no child intercepts it.

Comment: Seems you are right. Espresso clicks on screen but not emulate `performClick()` on view. Seems some view in the middle of the item intercepts click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RecyclerViewActions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html)

Just use:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

For example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void clickItem() {
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
        .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(o, click()));

    onView(withId(R.id.text))
        .check(matches(withText("XX")))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. That's actually first snipped in question. Problem here is that `Espresso.click()` has no effect. While custom `ViewAction` with `view.performClick()` works.

Comment: In which view did you define the onClickListener in your adapter ?